# Using virtualField to get SUM according to parent ID

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3, sum

I have a Location model and also a Event model

I want to get the SUM of all the Events for each Location

I thought I could do this by having the following extra model:

```
<?php
class Eventcount extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Eventcount';
    var $useTable = 'events';
    var $virtualFields = array(
        'event_count' => 'COUNT(*)'
    );  

}
?>
```

This is referenced as needed in the Location model.

However I thought this would do the JOIN using WHERE Location.ID = Eventcount.location_ID but it doesn't, instead in the debug code I get this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS `Eventcount__event_count`, `Eventcount`.`location_id` FROM `events` AS `Eventcount` WHERE `Eventcount`.`location_id` IN (6, 11, 13, 15, 7, 14, 4, 5, 10, 2, 9, 3, 1, 8)
```

So rather than a SUM of Events for each Location I get one single row for the first 
match with a SUM of all Events for every Location.

That is:

```
        [Eventcount] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [location_id] => 7
                        [event_count] => 2
                    )

            )
```

That number 2 next to event_count is the total number of Events in the database, not the total number where location_id = 7.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Appears I need a GROUP BY somewhere, but where to put it if I want to use this extra model in a find->all done on the parent hmmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationship is that a Location hasMany Events, I'd suggest using **counterCache** to automatically track the number of Events per Location. From the [counterCache page of 1.3 cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count):

> Instead of counting the records manually via find('count'), the model
>   itself tracks any addition/deleting towards the associated $hasMany
>   model and increases/decreases a dedicated integer field within the
>   parent model table.

So you'd add an `int` column to the Location model called `event_count`. In the Event model you'd add a line to the relationship with Location:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Location' => array(
        ...
        'counterCache' => true  // added to enable counter cache
    )
);
```

From then on the `event_count` in the Location model would be automatically incremented/decremented when you create/delete Events for each Location.